# How can i decode the payload from json web token?

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am using express. I am getting json web token BACK. In java script for example if i want to see what is in the payload i will use window atob method.But i need to do this also in back end so to make only admin users to acccess some route.How can i decode the payload from json web token so i get back for example the json object.

Comment: Are you using a JWT library in your backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Lib like `jsonwebtoken`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

Example:

```
var decoded = jwt.verify(YOUR_TOKEN, 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY')
```

That way you can check it is your token and get the decoded JSON object